# Django - Autopopulate non blank form field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Let's consider this model

```
class Session(models.Model):
  tutor = models.ForeignKey(User)
  start_time = models.DateTimeField()
  end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'm trying to post values for `start_time` and `end_time` and automatically give `tutor` the current logged in user.

My form is actually managing only `start_time` and `end_time`

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Session
    exclude = ['tutor']
```

And my view adds the `tutor`:

```
def post(request):
  """Session post"""
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SessionForm(request.POST)
    form.tutor = request.user
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      obj = {'posted': True}
      return HttpResponse(json.dumps(obj), mimetype='application/json')
    else:
      return render_to_response('planner/editor.html',
          form, context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

I'm getting a

> Column 'tutor_id' cannot be null

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Set tutor to **form.instance**

Instead of:

```
form.tutor = request.user
if form.is_valid():
  form.save()
```

You should have:

```
form.instance.tutor = request.user
if form.is_valid():
  form.save()
```

But personnaly I'd rather tweak form.instance after form.is_valid(), just before form.save().

Comment: I also think it's better to change `form.instance` after the `is_valid()`